# Vim under CMDer: How do I enable mouse support?

Tags: vim, cmder

For some reason, I can't get mouse support to work under CMDer.

It works normally under the regular CMD. I can click all I want all day. But I use CMDer as my development environment. It has temporary settings for my installation of CLang to use.

I went into the settings and enabled "Send Mouse Events to Console" but that does not appear to be doing anything. I even made sure to try

`:set mouse=a`

Which is on by default when ever I use the regular windows Command Prompt.

Comment: It works for me, with that option disabled. mouse is set in vim, also. Do you have a clean CMDer install?

Comment: Don't think so. Grabbed a prebuilt binary archive.

Comment: @robcsi May I ask for a copy of your binary? Or a small guide?

Comment: I didn't configure this in any way, I have default install as well.

Comment: I have the same problem and wonder if you ever solved it?

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by going to: **settings -> Mouse -> Mouse options: enable send mouse events to console -> save settings.** Then close the cmder and open again. You should be able to navigate into a vim script using the mouse left click.

[image]